# If Cell Contains XXX Then Return Corresponding Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
     A          B          C           D
1  Ross       Sales     John Guys    Finance 
2  Smith      Sales     Sam Andy     #N/A or False
3  Guys       Finance   Mike Ross    Sales
```

I'm putting this formula in cell "D1" but it's not giving me correct result

> =IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A:A,C:C)))>0,B:B)

INDEX MATCH function would not work because it's not exact value

What can I put in "D1" and down to give me result as in the table above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in D2,

```
=LOOKUP(1E+99, SEARCH(A2, C:C), B:B)
'or cut down the full column references
=LOOKUP(1E+99, SEARCH(A2, C$2:C$4), B$2:B$4)
'alternately as a wildcard MATCH
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH("*"&A2&"*",C:C, 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: LOOKUP_sEARCH]

Comment: What is 1E+99 for? I'm working with the sheet over 40k+ rows so should I put E1+99999 instead?

Comment: a) 1e99 is a 1 followed by 99 zeroes. It is an impossibly large number; one that can never be met and is used for that purpose. b) the second wildcard  MATCh would be better for you if you have 40K rows. c) NEVER use full column references with SUMPRODUCT. 40K is a lot but it is still a lot smaller than 1,048,576.

Comment: "*"&A2&"*" will only lookup one value in A2. How can I extend it to lookup a range? say A:A or A2:A6 etc